# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while mocking MessageHandler in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, integration

I have a simple Spring Integration configuration that works

```
@Configuration
public class FTPIntegration {


@Bean
public MessageChannel outputIntegrationChannel(ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    return MessageChannels
            .publishSubscribe()
            .errorHandler(errorHandler)
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpIntegration(ErrorHandler errorHandler, MessageHandler messageHandler) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(outputIntegrationChannel(errorHandler))
            .transform(Transformers.toJson())
            .handle(messageHandler)
            .get();
}
}
```

I want to prepare some integration tests using Mockito to mock, spy MessageHandler and ErrorHandler. So that's why I want to replace them in test configuration.

```
@Profile("test")
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
@Import(value = FTPIntegration.class)
public class TestConf {

@Bean
@Primary
public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return mock(ErrorHandler.class);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public MessageHandler messageHandler() {
    return mock(MessageHandler.class);
}
}
```

And use it in my test class

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConf.class)
public class FTPIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("outputIntegrationChannel")
private MessageChannel integrationChannel;
}
```

But with initialization I got an error that

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;

at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:84)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:70)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:57)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Is it a fault of my configuration or there is no possibility to use Mockito's components in Spring Integration?

When I use some simple method reference like returning
**log::error**
or 
**log::info**
in **MessageError** and **MessageHandler** it **works properly**.

I also tried to use 
    **MockIntegration.mockMessageHandler();** 
but result is the same (exception) because it use Mockito's mock underneath.

Comment: This means that the method `org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;` is not available in the runtime. Ususally, such problems are caused by lib version conflicts between the libs or by incomplete classpath in the runtime. Pls make sure you're using the compatible versions of SPring and Mockito and make sure you have all dependencies on the classpath in runtime.

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev you were right I had old mockito version. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Mockito was in 1.x version which was incompatible with Spring Integration with 5.x version. Upgrading Mockito into 2.x (2.22.0) fixed this issue and works with Spring Integration (5.0.8.RELEASE).